# How to quote selected text only when sending a reply in Outlook 365 Business?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm missing the Thunderbird function to have the selected text of a mail prepared as quote in the new mail when hiting the reply button.

I only found settings to change the arrangement of quotes which lead to full-blown replies which no-one needs as long as the conversation hierarchy is managed with mail headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, I am afraid there is no built-in option available to quote only selected text when replying a message in Outlook for Windows. You may send a feedback to [the Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/).